# dateFormatter string for date type 2013-03-24T02:15:23-08:00 using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I want to convert 2013-03-24T02:15:23-08:00 string to NSDate object. I tried formatter string `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss-Z`, but the NSDate object is coming as nil.

Below is my code for conversion:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss-Z"];
        NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:image.dateTaken];
```

Comment: 'T' to escape this character.

Comment: Also consider setting the `locale` as suggested in [Apple Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two errors in the date format string:

- The (literal) `T` character in the date format must be quoted as `'T'`.
- The format for a "ISO8601 time zone" like `-08:00` is `ZZZZZ`.
  Note that the minus sign is part of the time zone itself, not part of the format.

This should work:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
```

Comment: 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ' and 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ' both worked in this case. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @tek3: On iOS 7, both "ZZZZZ" and "Z" seem to work. On iOS 6, only the documented format "ZZZZZ" works (tested in the iOS 6 Simulator).

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-03-24T02:15:23-08:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];

dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: check the correct format or not [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss-Z"];

Answer (score 1):

2013-03-24T02:15:23-08:00 in this string Z is not the correct format for -08:00...

The correct format for Z is as follows

Z : GMT-08:00

or

Z : -0800

Please check the below link for your reference

http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

If you change the date string to to -0800 or GMT-08:00 you can get the correct date...