# JSON date to NSDate results to nil

Tags: ios, json, nsstring, nsdate

I have a date string in JSON format that looks like this: `2014-02-07T00:00:00+08:00`

And I'm trying to convert it to `NSDate` with format `MM/dd/yyyy`.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:datestring];
NSDateFormatter *newDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[newDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

NSString *newString = [newDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Date: %@, formatted date: %@", date, newString);
```

But the result is nil. What's wrong?

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522418/dateformatter-string-for-date-type-2013-03-24t021523-0800-objective-c/21522865#21522865

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct date format is:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx"];
```

or

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
```

See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

```
NSString *datestring = @"2014-02-07T00:00:00+08:00";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:datestring];
NSDateFormatter *newDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[newDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSString *newString = [newDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Date: %@, formatted date: %@", date, newString);
```

NSLog output:

> Date: 2014-02-06 16:00:00 +0000, formatted date: 02/06/2014